# Hash the contents of an columntype Array[Int] individually

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame of `Int, Array[Int]` with the values of

```
+---+------+
| _1|    _2|
+---+------+
|  1|   [1]|
|  1|   [2]|
|  2|[3, 4]|
+---+------+
```

I want to return DataFrame of

```
+---+------+------------------+
| _1|    _2|                _3|
+---+------+------------------+
|  1|   [1]|         [hash(1)]|
|  1|   [2]|         [hash(2)]|
|  2|[3, 4]|[hash(3), hash(4)]|
+---+------+------------------+
```

I originally attempted to convert the DataFrame into a dataset and to map the dataset. However, I am unable to reproduce the hash with MurmurHash3.
In short, I am unable to reproduce https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2165-L2168.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

I am open to any method to get my desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```
val df = Seq((1, Seq(1)), (1, Seq(2)), (2, Seq(3, 4))).toDF

df.selectExpr("*", "transform(_2, x -> hash(x)) AS _3").show
```

```
+---+------+--------------------+
| _1|    _2|                  _3|
+---+------+--------------------+
|  1|   [1]|        [-559580957]|
|  1|   [2]|        [1765031574]|
|  2|[3, 4]|[-1823081949, -39...|
+---+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! 
Just a followup, is there a map version of this?
Current with the DF method, I am deserializing and then serializing. I haven't found a map version that is consistent with the spark Murmur3Hash function.

Comment: Answering my own question, I realized I need the proper seed, which is not public information.